# Rework Function (capital F)

Tags: javascript, function, eval, content-security-policy

I am trying to get a Javascript speex library to run within a CSP protected environment. It runs great without CSP and I already fixed most "eval" problems. However - this one is giving me a headache:

```
this.interpolate = Function("buffer", toCompile);
```

See: https://github.com/grantgalitz/XAudioJS/blob/master/resampler.js

I tried something like

```
this.interpolate = function buffer () { return toCompile };
```

but that didn't work. Though I understand the .. well, basics of "Function" versus "function",  I can't find working fix.

Any help is appreciated.

Michaela

Comment: you need to rewrite `toCompile` but not as a `string` but as a `function`, for most parts its a peace of cake, but you might have some problem with loops. then in the last line: `this.interpolate = toCompile`.

Comment: Yeah .. I figured that much. This is indeed a pain in .. well .. you know :)

Comment: It is and unfortunately i'm afraid there's no way around it!

Comment: Got it. Thanks. You helped me to stop fooling around and go for the only possible solution.

Here's what I did (in the vent somebody stumbles over a situation like this):

I dumped that content of the function string to the console and re-formatted it into a function. Renamed all "this" into "that" and made the old "this" into a function parameter.

`//      this.interpolate = Function("buffer", toCompile);
        this.interpolate = function buffer(buffer) {
                return(Bla(buffer,this));
                }
`

We shouldn't probably use Function :)